# PowerShell command prompt has sometimes >>>> instead of one

Tags: powershell

How come sometimes there are `>>>>` istead of simply `>`?

Comment: I don't know if you can ever get `>>>>`, but you can get `>>` if PowerShell is waiting on you to complete a command. `dir a"` is not complete since there's another `"` expected, for example, so not until you enter a line with a `"` on it somewhere will the command be parsed and the prompt return to normal.

Comment: @JeroenMostert well there are four `>>>>` in my prompt. Is there a general way to stop it?

Comment: If the prompt is customized you should be able to discover that with `Get-Content Function:\Prompt`. Mine shows something along the lines of `$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1))`, which means `>` will be added as prompts nest. If you're in a nested prompt and you're not expecting to be in one, `exit` should take you up a level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**More than one `>`** in the (default<sup>[1]</sup>) prompt string shows up in two scenarios:

- **Typing an *incomplete command*** and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, in which case `>>` at the start of the following indicates that more input is needed to complete the command; however, this string is *always* `>>`, i.e. fixed at *2* `>` chars; while this *looks* like a nested prompt (see below), it isn't.
- **Inside a *nested* prompt**, where the *number* of `>` chars. indicates the nesting *depth*, as reflected in the automatic `$NestedPromptLevel` variable: a single `>` indicates the non-nested, top-level prompt at depth `0`, `>>` indicates a nested prompt of depth `1`, and so on. That said, a depth greater than `1` is unusual in practice.

  - A **nested prompt** is a **temporary, interactive sub-shell** that has full access to its parent shell's state and is **terminated by submitting `exit`**, at which point any ongoing script or function execution that was interrupted (suspended) by the nested prompt resumes.
  - The **primary use of nested prompts is in *debugging* and *troubleshooting***, such as in the context of tracking down *errors*:

    - A nested prompt is *automatically and invariably* entered when a [`Wait-Debugger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/wait-debugger) statement is executed.
    - Otherwise, entering a nested prompt is *offered* as the `[S] Suspend` choice of an *interactive menu*, in the following scenarios:

      - A command with a declared confirmation impact higher or equal to the current `$ConfirmPreference` value is executed, in which confirmation of the intent to execute the command is prompted for. For cmdlets and advanced functions/scripts you can trigger this confirmation prompt *on demand* with the
        `-Confirm` switch.
      - One of the `$*Preference` [preference variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables) is set to `'Inquire'`, and something is written to the [relevant output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection). Alternatively, on a per-command basis for cmdlets and advanced function/scripts, you can use
        `-*Action Inquire` [common parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters), though note that the *verbose* and *debug* streams only have *Boolean* parameters, `-Verbose` and `-Debug`<sup>[2]</sup>; for instance:

        - If `$DebugPreference` is `'Inquire'`, execution of any `Write-Debug` statement triggers the interactive menu.
        - If `$ErrorActionPreference` is `'Inquire'`, any error that occurs triggers the interactive menu, and choosing `[S] Suspend` to enter a nested prompt allows investigation of the error.
  - From *user code*, you can enter a nested prompt on demand with `$host.EnterNestedPrompt()` (which doesn't make sense *interactively*).

---

<sup>[1] Given that you can define a custom `prompt` function to determine the prompt string, you could hypothetically define it with multiple `>` chars. by default, though that is not advisable; e.g.: `function prompt { "$PWD>>> " }`. To see the current body of the `prompt` function, submit `$function:prompt`</sup>

<sup>[2] In *Windows PowerShell*, passing `-Debug` to a cmdlet or advanced function/script implies `'Inquire'`, but this was changed in PowerShell [Core] v6+ to `'Continue'` (only print the debug message, do not put up the menu) in order to be less disruptive.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to mkelement0's answer regarding nested prompts and interactivity:

In PowerShell, the use of nested prompts can be a highly effective strategy in certain scenarios, especially when developing a custom parser that utilizes Read-Host to gather user inputs.

This configuration allows users to dynamically inspect or modify variables within the current scope, providing a more interactive and immediate experience. Contrary to a debugger, which reveals the entire execution environment, this method enables targeted interactions with specific script elements based on user input. It proves particularly beneficial in cases where scripts require user-driven decisions or immediate data manipulation.

For example, if a user enters "/ps", you can activate a nested prompt that permits them to execute PowerShell commands within that specific context. This functionality can be extremely useful for tasks such as inspecting a variable or altering it as necessary, aiding in testing or making adjustments that the initial parser design might not have accounted for. Such flexibility significantly enhances the script’s utility and adaptability in real-time scenarios.